# Do homologically trivial embedded surfaces in 4-manifolds bound embedded 3-manifolds?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Everything here is smooth for simplicity.  This falls under the banner of: "Is homology what I think it is in low dimensions?"

Given a connected surface $F$ embedded in a 4-manifold $X^4$ with $[F] = 0$ where $[F] \in H_2(X; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ and where the normal bundle of $F$ is trivial, does it follow that there is an embedded 3-manifold $M^3$ in $X$ with $\partial M = F$?

Comment: It's more complicated than just a question about homology. Consider that the existence of [Seifert surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface) is nontrivial...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Well, it's pretty trivial if the surface need not be orientable... (Also, Seifert's algorithm is straightforward and the corresponding result holds in $S^n$.)

Comment: I guess it's easy to consider something is "straightforward" after it's been explained to you. I'd have been hard pressed to come up with it if I didn't already know it.

Comment: I think you can get an answer with the identification $K(\mathbb Z2\mathbb Z, 2) \to P^\infty(\mathbb C)$ : you can represent the cohomology class dual to $[F]$ by a map to $P^\infty(\mathbb C)$. By compactness, you can even get a map to $P^n(\mathbb C)$ and then use transversality to find a $M$.

Comment: If the notation $P^\infty(\mathbb{C})$ denotes the infinite projective space, unfortunately this is a $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ and not a $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},2)$. (And $P^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},1)$)